Как найти число у которого 5000 делителей?
Необходимо найти наименьшее число, имеющее 5000 делителей. Я порыскал по интернету, нашёл самый(вроде бы) оптимизированный алгоритм на python,написал такой код:
from sympy import factorint
from time import time
def count_divisors(n):
    factors = factorint(n)
    count = 1
    for factor in factors.values():
        count *= (factor + 1)
    return count
a = 1000000
t0 = 0
t1 = time()
while True:
    if count_divisors(a) == 5000:
        print(f"5000 делителей у числа {a}")
        break
    a += 1
    t2 = time()
    if t2 - t1 > 60:
        t0 += 1
        print(f"Работаем {t0} минут. Текущее число - {a}")
        t1 = time()

time добавил, чтобы не свихнуться от неизвестности. Проблема в том, что код работает уже почти 3 часа, а число дошло до 213 миллиардов, но пока глухо. А дальше каждое число будет тратить всё больше и больше ресурсов, пока комп не зависнет. Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать обратную функцию(дабы искала число по количеству делителей) или хоть сократить диапазон поиска?
Upd: 5000 любых делителей, так что 1 и само число также подходят

Вы понимаете, что делает count_divisors? Может быть, использовать этот принцип с числом 5000?

Перемножаем числа от 2 до 5001 - это наше число, имеющее 5000 делителей.

Но это может быть не минимальное число

Простых делителей или любых делителей? А 1 - это делитель или нет? А делители должны быть все уникальные или нет? Задачка поставлена недостаточно чётко (  А так то да, просто перемножаете подходящие под определение "делителей" числа, начиная от минимального, в количестве 5000 штук - и всё. Это будет именно минимальное такое число. Потому что зависимость прямая: чем меньше делители - тем меньше их произведение, а мы берём делители, начиная от самых маленьких. А число этих делителей фиксировано при этом (5000).

Кстати, отдельно непонятно - что вы будете делать с этим числом. Если это действительно произведение чисел 23...*5001, то считается то оно моментально, но в нём будет 16330 десятичных разрядов, это больше чем 200 строк по 80 цифр в строке.

"5000 любых делителей, так что 1 и само число также подходят" - ну, наверное, всё-таки ещё уникальность есть, да? Иначе можно 5000 раз единицы между собой перемножить и получится 1. А если уникальность есть, то просто перемножаете числа 1, 2, ... 5000 и всё. Если вы попробуете любое из этих чисел заменить на какое-то другое, то вам нужно будет взять в качестве этого другого числа как минимум число 5001 (все числа меньше уже нами использованы) и, очевидно, произведение в этом случае станет больше, чем было. Так что мы получили наименьшее число с 5000 делителей.

Считается такое произведение за время порядка 10 миллисекунд.

https://oeis.org/A005179 вот тут можете порядок чисел посмотреть)

найти наименьшее число, имеющее 5000 делителей Строго 5000 или не менее чем 5000?

Получается вот что. Поскольку теория чисел говорит нам, что число, которое разлагается на простые множители в виде 2^p*3^q*5^r..., имеет число делителей
num_divisors = (p+1)*(q+1)*(r+1)*...

то мы можем разложить число num_divisors=5000 = 2*2*2*5*5*5*5 на множители всем возможными способами (их немало, но обозримое количество), и для каждого разложения посчитать результат:
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17]
minn = -1

def fmx(lst):
    num = 1
    global minn
    for i, p in enumerate(lst):
        num *= primes[i]**(p-1)
    if minn == -1:
        minn = num
    else:
        minn = min(num, minn)


def f5000(lst=[], p2=3, p5=4):
    if p2+p5==0:
        fmx(lst)
        return
    for i in range(p2+1):
        for j in range(p5+1):
            if i+j:
                f5000(lst + [2**i * 5**j], p2-i, p5-j)


f5000()

print(minn)

Результат
>>> 4727833110000
2^4 * 3^4 * 5^4 * 7^4 * 11 * 13 * 17


Если вы ищете минимальное число, у которого ровно 5000 делителей, то посмотрите соседний ответ. Или посмотрите раздел = 5000 ниже в этом ответе. А пока
≥ 5000
В статье Сверхсоставное число описаны числа, которые имеют число делителей, большее чем у любого предыдущего. Наша задача – найти первое сверхсоставное число с количеством делителей больше заданного порога.
Сверхсоставные числа имеют вид
∏i pici, где
pi – последовательные простые числа,
ci – невозрастающая последовательность степеней.
Произведение конечно, так как начиная с некоторого i ci становится равным нулю.
Число делителей равно d(∏i pici) = ∏i (ci + 1). (статья Функция делителей).
Наша задача перебрать все невозрастающие последовательности ci, у которых ∏i (ci + 1) больше заданного порога, и выбрать из них одну с минимальным ∏i pici.
Ещё понадобится свойство монотонности: если в ci увеличить любой элемент на единицу, увеличатся и произведение и число делителей. Всё, этого достаточно чтобы написать код.
is_prime и next_prime отыскивают последовательные простые. Прошу прощения за их медлительность. В нашей задаче большие простые числа не понадобятся, а так код проще.
search отыскивает минимальное сверхсоставное число с нужным количеством делителей. Поиск рекурсивный. Поддерживается последовательность степеней c, количество делителей n_divs и само число-кандидат product. least_product хранит минимального кандидата, что ускоряет поиск (выше было про монотонность).
def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % d != 0 for d in range(2, n - 1))


def next_prime(n):
    while not is_prime(n):
        n += 1
    return n


def search(target):
    least_product = float('inf')
    p = [1]
    c = [target - 1]

    def search(i, n_divs, product):
        nonlocal least_product
        if i >= len(p):
            p.append(next_prime(p[-1] + 1))
            c.append(0)

        if product >= least_product:
            return

        if n_divs >= target:
            if product < least_product:
               least_product = product

        if c[i] > 0:
            search(i + 1, n_divs, product)
        if c[i - 1] > c[i]:
            c[i] += 1
            search(i, n_divs // c[i] * (c[i] + 1), product * p[i])
            c[i] -= 1

    search(1, 1, 1)
    return least_product


print(search(int(input())))

Почти мгновенно можно отыскать ответ для пяти тысяч и восемь секунд нужно для миллиарда:

$ time echo 5000 | python highly-composite-number.py 
293318625600

real  0m0.036s
user  0m0.024s
sys   0m0.008s

$ time echo 1000000000 | python highly-composite-number.py 
474386058264023040500951689662949694304000

real  0m8.062s
user  0m8.056s
sys   0m0.004s


Поиск устроен так чтобы быстро построить праймориал с нужным количеством делителей. Сам он обычно не является минимальным ответом, но даёт хорошее ограничение сверху. Для 5000 это:
304250263527210 = 2·3·5·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31·37·41
У него 8192 (= 213) делителей, а вектор степеней ci состоит из триннадцати единиц.
Это не лучшее решение. Чтобы отыскать минимум, поиск проверяет ещё около девяти тысяч векторов. Вот некоторые, в порядке улучшения разультата:



кандидат
разложение
число делителей




304250263527210
2·3·5·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31·37·41
8192


14841476269620
22·3·5·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31·37
6144


6016814703900
22·32·52·7·11·13·17·19·23·29·31
6912


1358635578300
22·32·52·72·11·13·17·19·23·29
5184


1030689059400
23·32·52·72·112·13·17·19·23
5184


776363187600
24·32·52·7·11·13·17·19·23·29
5760


465817912560
24·33·5·7·11·13·17·19·23·29
5120


401567166000
24·33·53·7·11·13·17·19·23
5120


374796021600
25·32·52·72·11·13·17·19·23
5184


321253732800
26·33·52·7·11·13·17·19·23
5376


293318625600
26·34·52·72·11·13·17·19
5040



= 5000
Чтобы перебрать все числа, имеющие ровно 5000 делителей, нужно разложить 5000 во всевозможные произведения и для каждого произведения составить число с пятью тысячами делителей. Например:



5000 =
соответствующее число с пятью тысячами делителей




= 5000
pi4999


= 625·8
pi624pj7


= 5·5·5·5·2·2·2
pi4pj4pk4pl4pmpnpo



Любое число вида pi624pj7, где pi и pj различные простые, будет иметь ровно 5000 делителей. Рецепт прост: различные простые возводятся в степени на единицу меньшие множителей из разложения.
Так как мы ищем минимальные кандидаты, то простые будем брать из начала ряда и расположим множители по убыванию. Всего у пяти тысяч – 57 разложений.
Код не очень эффективный, зато простой:
def is_prime(n):
    return all(n % d != 0 for d in range(2, n - 1))


def next_prime(n):
    while not is_prime(n):
        n += 1
    return n


def search(target):
    p = [2]

    def factorizations(limit, n):
        if n == 1:
            yield ()
            return
        for d in range(2, limit + 1)[::-1]:
            if n % d == 0:
                for f in factorizations(d, n // d):
                    yield (d, ) + f

    def candidates():
        nonlocal p
        for f in factorizations(target, target):
            while len(p) < len(f):
                p.append(next_prime(p[-1] + 1))

            r = 1
            for p_i, f_i in zip(p, f):
                r *= p_i ** (f_i - 1)
            yield r

    return min(candidates())


print(search(int(input())))

Для 5000 считает мгновенно. Для миллиарда надо подождать три минуты:

$ time echo 5000 | python highly-composite-number.py
4727833110000

real  0m0.030s
user  0m0.024s
sys   0m0.004s

$ time echo 1000000000 | python highly-composite-number.py
683175381189232829757128698827279802247046720000

real  2m39.379s
user  2m38.400s
sys   0m0.804s



Вы не ту задачу решаете, что я. У вас 5040 делителей, у меня ровно 5000

@MBo, спасибо, я уже заметил. Условие поставлено не совсем ясно. Если у меня в кармане 5040 рублей, то 5000 тоже там есть. :) Но, возможно, вы правы.

Да, не хватает уточнения "ровно 5000" или "не менее 5000"

@MBo, теперь я точно решаю ту задачу. Хоть и не знаю какую. :)
